# Unable to access shiny server in docker container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Dockerized R Shiny app on Google Cloud VM. It was running well but from yesterday I am not able to access the shiny server. I have checked the docker logs and it gives me below message:

```
**[2019-03-13T14:56:11.496] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.7.890 (Node.js v8.10.0)  
[2019-03-13T14:56:11.498] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"  
[2019-03-13T14:56:11.559] [WARN] shiny-server - Running as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be running more securely as non-root.  
[2019-03-13T14:56:11.562] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838**
```

So, does it means the shiny server is running? If YES then why I am not able to access it from a browser (on the browser it gives me an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`)?

**Note:** The port `3838` (default shiny server port) is whitelisted from VM.

Comment: Have you exposed the port in your docker container?

Comment: Yes @Samuel, I have published the port by using below lines in docker-compose.yml file:  

ports:  
      - "80:3838"